# WPF XAML Using Mouse Action Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am learning the WPF 4.5 Unleashed book. When I tried to incorporate Mouse Action Event such as MouseEnter or MouseDoubleClick for the Button by typing the code manually, the compiler told me it could not find the reference for the Mouse Action Event. However, when I use the double Tab shortcut, everything works well. What could possibly be the issue? I have bold the trouble code below.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationLearning0001.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="513.265" Width="748.469">
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">

    </Menu>
    <StackPanel Name="ButtonBar" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90">
            </RotateTransform>
        </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
        **<Button Name="Panel1Button"  MouseEnter="Panel1Button_MouseEnter">
            Toolbox
        </Button>**


    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Background="White" Margin="0,0,2,3">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Black" Foreground="White"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Content= "Start Page"/>
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Header="Start" />
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Header="Recent" />
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Header="Option" />
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Header="Get Start"> 
         <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>Article number1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Article number2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Article number3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Article number4</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>

    </GroupBox>


</Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

The double click not only puts it in the XAML code, put it also creates the code behind in the .cs file of:

```
private void Panel1Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Until you add the code behind yourself, if you are doing it manually, then the error is correct. In addition, when manually coding be sure to include `(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` in the function call or it may not recognize it as a valid function call to the MouseEvent.